# change style of an existing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyside

I have a matplotlib figure embeded in a widget in Qt application.

I create it like this:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

self.figure = Figure()
self.widget = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
```

During the lifetime of the chart and the widget I can add some lines, bars, axes etc. To clear the chart I use:

```
self.figure.clear()
self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

To add some lines:

```
ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, values, etc...)
self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

Which means I do not destroy and recreate the figure each time it is changed, I am reusing the existing figure. But is there an option to change the complete style of the figure using something like matplotlib.pyplot.style during its lifetime? Or do I need to always create a new figure (and new widget) when I want to change the style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the style is like changing `rcParams`, it won't change the properties of already created objects. This wouldn't fit well with the way matplotlib works.

Note that some objects are created as you interact with the plot, for example tick labels. When you zoom and pan new tick labels may be created on the fly and reflect changes in style / `rcParams`.

You can choose between recreating the objects and writing code that explicitly changes their properties.